# How to show template parameter info in QtCreator?

Tags: templates, qt-creator

In QtCeator you can get a tooltip for function paramter info by using Ctrl + Space inside the parenthesis while typing, but his doesn't work for template parameters.
Is a shortcut to show parameter information for templates arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is no direct way to show template parameter info, so the only workaround I have found is to look at the parameter info from the autocomplete pop up.